# It's possibile to extract a raw frame from an h264 file?

Tags: video, video-streaming, h.264, video-processing

I need to have a raw image from my sensor, but I have only h264 video files.
Is there a way to extract a frame raw?

Comment: What do you mean by 'extract'? Do you mean decode? Because, yes, there is obvious ally a way.

Comment: what's the way to obtain a raw file from a frame then?

Comment: Just in case you mean raw as in the exact original before it was encoded into H.264 - most H.264 encoded will be at least a little bit 'lossy' so it will not be an exact frame that you extract but for most purposes this does not matter.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/):

Extract a raw H.264 frame:

`ffmpeg -i input.h264 -c:v copy -frames:v 1 -f h264 frame.h264`

Extract the frame as `PNG`:

`ffmpeg -i input.h264 -frames:v 1 -f image2 frame.png`

To extract a specfic frame (25th frame):

`ffmpeg -i input.h264 -c:v libx264 -filter:v "select=gte(n\,25)" -frames:v 1 -f h264 frame.h264`

Comment: it seems that the synthax is wrong: Unrecognized option 'c:v'
Failed to set value 'libx264' for option 'c:v'

Comment: The syntax is OK. You have either an extremely outdated `ffmpeg` or you didn't compile it with `x264` support.  See the compilation guide here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide

Comment: I've just done apt-get from my ubuntu. Let me look better

Comment: If you still have issues post the full console output 'cause maybe it's something else.